# Bind on Db2 using C#

Tags: c#, cmd, db2

I want to execute bind statements on Db2 for z/OS V12 using C#. In db2cmd it works fine:

```
db2 bind filename.bnd owner OOO qualifier QQQ collection CCC explain no grant public
```

In C# I start a db2cmd process. I want to write to the StandardInput and log the output, but neither worked: The commands are not executed and I do not get any output back.

```
using (var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "db2cmd",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true
    }
})
{    
    p.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };
    p.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) => { Console.WriteLine(e.Data); };

    p.Start();
    p.BeginOutputReadLine();
    p.BeginErrorReadLine();

    p.StandardInput.WriteLine($"db2 connect to {DataBase} user {User.Userid} using {User.Password}");
    p.StandardInput.WriteLine("db2 bind filename.bnd owner OOO qualifier QQQ collection CCC explain no grant public");

    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Please specify what happens when you run it. What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: stdout and stderr are both empty and the commands are not executed

Comment: compare behavior with UseShellExecute true, verify db2cmd is on the PATH, and check arguments to db2cmd (e.g. -i , -c etc).

Comment: It works with the argument -i. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was resolved by supplying the argument `-i` to the db2cmd.exe program.

This argument is [documented](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2cmd-open-db2-command-window) as:

> Run command following the -i option while sharing Db2 command window
> and inheriting file handles. For example, db2cmd -i dir runs the dir
> command in the same Db2 command window."